# How to rotate a 2D gameobject on z axes with Mathf.Clamp on 2 areas?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, 2d

I want to rotate a 2D game object on the z axis. That game object should only face the Player when he is in between 2 areas. The Z-axis should be clamped between -45 to 45 and 135 to 225.

[Example Image of the rotations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gnqZ.png)

(The green are is where the function: `LookAtTarget()` should be applied to)

Right now I'm using this code to bypass the problem, but it doesn't feel very satisfying:

```
    public virtual void LookAtTarget()
{
    float rotationZ = direction.transform.rotation.z;
    direction.transform.right = target.position - transform.position;

    if (rotationZ > -0.25F && rotationZ < 0.25F || rotationZ > 0.975F)
    {
        transform.right = target.position - transform.position;
    }

    Debug.Log(rotationZ);

}
```

I'm using this type of code because when I'm talking to eulerAngles I can't clamp the value between -45 and 45 and because -45 its like 315 degree for unity, so I can't go into the negative numbers. Also I'm declearing the rotation from another game object that should tell me when the Player is in the specific range.

I hope i could explain my problem. TY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Transform.rotation` is the rotation of the transform expressed as a `Quaternion`. To get the rotation around the z-axis, use `direction.transform.eulerAngles.z`. Always use `eulerAngles` unless you understand `Quaternions`.

I cannot understand what your code is doing, but here is an idea to clamp rotation. This code is untested. The key is Mathf.DeltaAngle(a, b) which returns the shortest angle (range of [-180, 180]) from a to b, even if the angles wrap around.

```
float maxAngle = 45f;//insert your max/min angles
float minAngle = -45f;

float midAngle = (maxAngle + minAngle) / 2f;//convert max/min angles to a center angle and how far from the center angle
float angleRange = maxAngle - midAngle;

Vector2 targetRelativePos = target.position - transform.position;
float targetAngle = Mathf.Atan2(targetRelativePos.y, targetRelativePos.z) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;//make sure everything is in degrees

float targetAngleDifference = Mathf.DeltaAngle(midAngle, targetAngle);
if(Mathf.Abs(targetAngleDifference) > angleRange){
    //outside of min/max angles
    if(targetAngleDifference > 0){
        //your angle is too big, consider setting it to maxAngle
    }else{
        //your angle is too small, consider setting it to minAngle
    }
}
```